# Is it bad practice to create an npm module that requires an external program

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

Would it be a good idea for me to publish an `npm` module that requires an external program that hasn't been published to npm (such as `python`), and installs it as a `postinstall` or `preinstall` hook?

Answer (score 0):

No.
A major percentage of npm modules depend upon some other npm module.
That's is how the entire node ecosystem works.

The only catch is, if you are making an npm module, all of it's external dependency should he equally available for everyone.

Comment: I meant a program such as `python` that has not been published to npm